# Morphological analysis of words with MRJob and Pymorphy2

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, mrjob

Can anyone help with the MRJob and Pymorphy2? I am new to python and hadoop. I sort of understood how to perform text tokenisation, but I cannot understand how to morphologically disassemble the resulting tokens using Pymorphy2.  Maybe I am doing something obvious wrong, but I do not understand.
This is my code:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import re, pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
WORD_RE = re.compile(r"[\w']+")

     class MRMorphWord(MRJob):

        def mapper(self, _, line): 
            for word in WORD_RE.findall(line):            
                yield (word.lower(), 1)

        def reducer(self, _, word):
            for i in word:
                p = morph.parse(word)[0] 
                yield p                  

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MRMorphWord.run()
```

Here is the error message:

```
parse
    word_lower = word.lower()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: i handed in reducer (self, word, morph) and get this error:                                       
`for out_key, out_value in reducer(key, values) or ():
  File "MrJobMorph.py", line 23, in reducer
    p = morph.parse(word)[0]
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'parse'`